# gulp-inject is giving wrong relative path

Tags: html, npm, gulp, gulp-inject

I've been having trouble with this useful tool and I don't know what to do anymore, that's why I come here to ask for your help.

This is my directory structure:

```
 - Project root
 |-  dist
     |-css
     |-js

 |-  source
     |- css
     |- js
     |-index.html

 |-gulpfile.js
 |-index.html
```

So, I'm using gulp to inject my css,js from the source folder, into my dist folder, minified, concatenated, etc. Then, inject that into my index.html in the source folder and spit in on the project root folder.
This is the code:

```
//Injects assets (css,js) into index.html automatically
gulp.task('inject',['sass','concat-css','concat-js'],function(){
    //Target to inject
    var target = gulp.src('source/index.html');


    //Sources to be injected

    var cssFiles = gulp.src('./dist/assets/css/*.css',{read:false});
    var jsFiles = gulp.src('./dist/assets/js/*.js',{read:false});
    //Merge resources into one
    var sources = es.merge(cssFiles,jsFiles);


    //Injecting bower.json dependencies and other resources

    return target.pipe(inject(sources),{
       ignorePath:'dist/',
        addRootSlash:false
    })
        .pipe(wiredep({ignorePath:'../'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

   });
```

The issue is that the path to the dist folder on the index.html is like this:

```
"/dist/css/stylesheet.css"
```

Causing error, because it should be : `"dist/css/stylesheet.css"

As you can see in the code, I've used the inject's options, ignorePath, addRootSlash, relative:true , and nothing seems to work. The same thing was happening to wiredep, but this one is accepting the ignorePath options so everything is fine.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Any luck?

Comment: @danm07 Unfortunately not, I end up hardcoding the link on the html source, because it wasn't going to change anyways. There will always be a stylesheet.css in the dist folder, so I hardcoded that bitch and quit pulling my hair off with the issue. I ended up using wiredep instead of gulp-inject btw.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you mistakenly put the `inject` options as a second parameter on the `pipe` function.  Try:

```
target.pipe(inject(sources, { ignorePath: 'dist/', addRootSlash: false }))
```

Comment: Don't you mean `target.pipe(inject(sources, { ignorePath: 'dist/', addRootSlash: false }))`  ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set *relative* option in the *inject* like this:

```
inject(sources, { relative: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the two option od gulp inject:
[ignorePath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#optionsignorepath) and [addRootSlash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#optionsaddrootslash)

```
var injectOptions = {
     addRootSlash: false,
     ignorePath: 'dist/'
};
target.pipe(inject(sources),injectOptions)
```

Comment: It should be in this way:
target.pipe(inject(sources,injectOptions))

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is old.
But for everyone with the same problem, like in my case.

Setting

```
var options = {
   relative: false,
   addRootSlash: false,
   ignorePath: 'dist/',
   addPrefix: './js'
};
return gulp.src(['./index.html'])
   .pipe(inject(stream, options))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('temp/'));
```

does the trick for me.
I had to remove the path by setting 'ignorePath' and then 'removeRootSlash' and 'addPrefix' for the destination folder.

See the More Examples section at [npm gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#more-examples) and the [addPrefix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#optionsaddprefix) part.